# Pandas: vertical look up using two columns and two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, join, lookup

Given the following dataframes:

df1:

```
    ID  A           B           
0   0   138.610513  34.860445   
2   2   139.307536  34.919052
```

df2:

```
    ID  A           B           CAT 
0   0   138.610513  34.860445   a
1   1   138.523152  34.807862   b
2   2   139.307536  34.919052   c
3   3   138.620263  34.883671   b
```

How can I look up the values in `CAT` and add them to `df1` as a new column?

I have tried this:

```
df1['CAT']=df1[['A'],['B']].map(df2[['A'],['B']])
```

But I get:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Expected output:

df1:

```
    ID  A           B           CAT 
0   0   138.610513  34.860445   a
2   2   139.307536  34.919052   c
```

This is just a test case. In my real problem, I cannot use the IDs as a reference because they are not consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `merge`. Looks like `id` too is mapped.

```
In [4820]: df1.merge(df2)
Out[4820]:
   ID           A          B CAT
0   0  138.610513  34.860445   a
1   2  139.307536  34.919052   c
```

If not, specify keys in `on`, and selectively pick needed columns in `df2`

```
In [4825]: df1.merge(df2[['A', 'B', 'CAT']], on=['A', 'B'])
Out[4825]:
   ID           A          B CAT
0   0  138.610513  34.860445   a
1   2  139.307536  34.919052   c
```

Comment: What if `df2` has a bunch of columns that I don't need? What if I only need `CAT`? I have specified that IDs are different in my real case.